# Sending a songlist containing track no, title, artist, album, genre and duration over a socket?

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming

I want to send these songs details to another phone over socket by using android application.
Like from server to client.
I have a full list of song title in a string.
Please tell me which approach to follow.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't just send these infos to a phone with a programm. You could use an app to do this, but that is probably not what you want. I'd just download QPython3 on both phones. It is an awesome Python 3 Compiler and Editor. Here you can write a simple Python script with socket (just google "python socket tutorial") and send it to the second phone.